# Why does fmt.Printf accept a byte array for %x in Go

Tags: go

I'm pretty new to Go. I want to know the exact difference between arrays and slices so please forgive me if I'm too obsessive over the spec.

In documentation for package [`fmt`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/), it says for `Printf` that `%x` can accept strings and slices of bytes. It said nothing about arrays of bytes. But in fact, if I put an array of bytes in it, it prints out fine too!

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  var b [6]byte
  for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
    b[i] = 'a'
  }
  fmt.Printf("%s\n", b) // "aaaaaa"
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why? AFAIK, bytes array and slices cannot implicitly convert to each other.

Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct that you can't implicitly convert slices and arrays.

A slice is a small data structure with 3 elements which are a pointer to some memory, the length of the memory, and the capacity of the memory.

However an array is just a block of memory.

Go passes everything by value in functions meaning that when you call `Printf` with the array, the whole of the memory of the array is passed to the function.  When you call it with a slice, the whole of the slice structure is passed to `Printf`.  However the slice structure contains a pointer to the underlying memory so this is very like passing a pointer to an array.

`Printf` uses lots of introspection to print its values.  All the arguments to `Printf` are converted to `interface{}` types which means they are boxed up with a type in a small structure.  `Printf` then examines these interface values, inspects the type and works out how to print the values.  For most `%` types that `Printf` undestands it can take quite a few types and it attempts to print them in a user friendly way.

For example `%x` can take an `int` which is printed in hex, or a slice, or an array as you've discovered.

So in summary

- array *is* contiguous memory
- slice is a structure *containing* a pointer to contiguous memory
- an interface value is a small structure containing a pointer to a type and the value
- `Printf` takes `interface{}` values
- It introspects the `interface{}` values to print lots of different things

I hope that explanation is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I took a look under [print.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/fmt/print.go) and found that when I'm passing a byte array, it calls `printReflectValue`. Then it makes a slice and copies the content.

Comment: That's a really nice break-down!